# Error in Maple's CellDecomposition Command

Tags: computational-geometry, rootfinding

I have a simple system that I want to process with the `CellDecomposition` command of Maple. I don't know why Maple is giving an error here! The code is

```
restart; 
f1 := 4*b*(5*b*(13*t^2-tau^2)*(t^2+tau^2)^6-3*a*5*t^6-63*t^4*tau^2+35*t^2*tau^4+7*tau^6)); 
f2 := 56*b*tau*(5*b*(t^2+tau^2)^6+a*(9*t^4-30*t^2*tau^2+9*tau^4)); f3 := 1-z*t;
with(RootFinding[Parametric])

m := CellDecomposition([f1 = 0, f2 = 0, f3 = 0], [t, tau, z])
```

and the error is:

```
Error, (in RootFinding:-Parametric:-CellDecomposition) The number of polynomials is smaller than the number of unknowns
```

The number of polynomials is obviously the same as the number of variables here!

Comment: I do not have the reputation to make a comment so I'll make my comment an answer. Since I don't know what maple is please realize that with this comment I'm only trying to help.
In looking at it from my completely ignorant perspective I do not know what a and b are. To me those are 'unknowns'. Sorry if this was a waste of your time.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the problem is that there's a factor of `b` that is common between `f1` and `f2`. If I divide both by `b` then I get a meaningful answer for this modified system.

Looking at the `CellPlot` of the result, it seems that this decomposition is invariant under multiplying `b` by a positive value. (There are different cells for `b` positive or negative, separated at `b = 0`, but otherwise the only interesting stuff happens in the `a` direction.) So that suggests that for nonzero `b`, the picture will be the same for the modified system and the original system... or does it?

<sup>Disclaimer: I work for Maplesoft, but I don't really know anything about the `RootFinding:-Parametric` package.</sup>

<sup>Edit: I talked to someone who *does* know about `RootFinding:-Parametric`, and he confirmed that this is indeed a bug. Am now submitting into our bug tracking system.</sup>